# numpy merge sorted array to an new array?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

Is there any way we can do something like merge in mergesort using numpy function?

some function like merge:

```
a = np.array([1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
c = merge(a, b) # c == np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I wish I could get high performance for large data thanks to numpy

Comment: Take a look at this answer which gives a very efficient solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12427633/58866

Comment: possible duplicate of [combine two arrays and sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427146/combine-two-arrays-and-sort)

Comment: do you want concatenation only, or sorting?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use

```
from numpy import concatenate, sort

c = concatenate((a,b))
c.sort(kind='mergesort')
```

I am afraid you can't do better than this, unless you write your own sorting function as a python extension, à la `cython`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427146/combine-two-arrays-and-sort) question for a similar problem, but keeping only the unique values in the merged array. The benchmarks and comments there are insightful as well.

Comment: Well, probably that is the best way. I searched a lot of the relevant answers, but it seems it always have to be this...

Comment: This solution is O(n log n), while merging the two arrays is O(n).

Answer (score 12):

The [sortednp](https://gitlab.sauerburger.com/frank/sortednp) package implements an efficient merge of sorted numpy-arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import sortednp
a = np.array([1,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
c = sortednp.merge(a, b) # c == np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Inspired by Sander's post, I measured numpy's mergesort (v1.17.4), Sander's answer, and sortednp (v0.2.1) for different array-sizes and ratios of the sizes between a and b using the following code:

```
from timeit import timeit as t
import sortednp as snp
import numpy as np

def numpy_mergesort(a, b):
    c = np.concatenate((a,b))
    c.sort(kind='mergesort')
    return c

def sanders_merge(a, b):
    if len(a) < len(b):
        b, a = a, b
    c = np.empty(len(a) + len(b), dtype=a.dtype)
    b_indices = np.arange(len(b)) + np.searchsorted(a, b)
    a_indices = np.ones(len(c), dtype=bool)
    a_indices[b_indices] = False
    c[b_indices] = b
    c[a_indices] = a
    return c

results = []

for size_factor in range(3):
    for max_digits in range(3, 8):
        size = 10**max_digits
        # size difference of a factor 10 here makes the difference!
        a = np.arange(size // 10**size_factor, dtype=np.int)
        b = np.arange(size, dtype=np.int)
        assert np.array_equal(numpy_mergesort(a, b), sanders_merge(a, b))
        assert np.array_equal(numpy_mergesort(a, b), snp.merge(a, b))
        classic = t(lambda: numpy_mergesort(a, b), number=10)
        sanders = t(lambda: sanders_merge(a, b), number=10)
        snp_result = t(lambda: snp.merge(a, b), number=10)
        results.append((size_factor, max_digits, classic, sanders, snp_result))

text_format = " ".join(["{:<18}"] * 5)
print(text_format.format("log10(size factor)", "log10(max size)", "np mergesort", "Sander's merge", "sortednp"))
table_format = "            ".join(["{:.5f}"] * 5)
for result in results:
    print(table_format.format(*result))
```

The results show that sortednp consistently is the fastest implementation:

```
log10(size factor) log10(max size)    np mergesort       Sander's merge     sortednp          
0.00000            3.00000            0.00016            0.00062            0.00005
0.00000            4.00000            0.00135            0.00469            0.00029
0.00000            5.00000            0.01160            0.03813            0.00292
0.00000            6.00000            0.14952            0.54160            0.03527
0.00000            7.00000            2.00566            5.91691            0.67119
1.00000            3.00000            0.00005            0.00017            0.00002
1.00000            4.00000            0.00019            0.00058            0.00014
1.00000            5.00000            0.00304            0.00633            0.00137
1.00000            6.00000            0.03743            0.06893            0.01828
1.00000            7.00000            0.62334            1.01523            0.38732
2.00000            3.00000            0.00004            0.00015            0.00002
2.00000            4.00000            0.00012            0.00028            0.00013
2.00000            5.00000            0.00217            0.00275            0.00122
2.00000            6.00000            0.03457            0.03205            0.01524
2.00000            7.00000            0.51307            0.50120            0.34335
```

Answer (score 4):

When one array is considerably larger than the other, a decent speedup (5-fold on my pc) can be obtained by doing a np.searchorted, which is limited in speed primarily by searching insertion indices of the smaller array:

```
import numpy as np

def classic_merge(a, b):
    c = np.concatenate((a,b))
    c.sort(kind='mergesort')
    return c

def new_merge(a, b):
    if len(a) < len(b):
        b, a = a, b
    c = np.empty(len(a) + len(b), dtype=a.dtype)
    b_indices = np.arange(len(b)) + np.searchsorted(a, b)
    a_indices = np.ones(len(c), dtype=bool)
    a_indices[b_indices] = False
    c[b_indices] = b
    c[a_indices] = a
    return c
```

Timing gives:

```
from timeit import timeit as t

results = []
for size_digits in range(2, 8):
    size = 10**size_digits
    # size difference of a factor 10 here makes the difference!
    a = np.arange(size // 10, dtype=np.int)
    b = np.arange(size, dtype=np.int)
    classic = t(lambda: classic_merge(a, b), number=10)
    new = t(lambda: new_merge(a, b), number=10)
    results.append((size_digits, classic, new))

if True:
    text_format = " ".join(["{:<15}"] * 3)
    print(text_format.format("log10(size)", "Classic", "New"))
    table_format = "         ".join(["{:.5f}"] * 3)
    for result in results:
        print(table_format.format(*result))

log10(size)     Classic         New            
2.00000         0.00009         0.00027
3.00000         0.00021         0.00030
4.00000         0.00233         0.00082
5.00000         0.02827         0.00601
6.00000         0.33322         0.06059
7.00000         4.40571         0.86764
```

When a and b are roughly of equal length differences are smaller:

```
from timeit import timeit as t

results = []
for size_digits in range(2, 8):
    size = 10**size_digits
    # same size
    a = np.arange(size , dtype=np.int)
    b = np.arange(size, dtype=np.int)
    classic = t(lambda: classic_merge(a, b), number=10)
    new = t(lambda: new_merge(a, b), number=10)
    results.append((size_digits, classic, new))

if True:
    text_format = " ".join(["{:<15}"] * 3)
    print(text_format.format("log10(size)", "Classic", "New"))
    table_format = "         ".join(["{:.5f}"] * 3)
    for result in results:
        print(table_format.format(*result))

log10(size)     Classic         New            
2.00000         0.00026         0.00087
3.00000         0.00108         0.00182
4.00000         0.01257         0.01243
5.00000         0.16333         0.12692
6.00000         1.05006         0.49186
7.00000         8.35967         5.93732
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast new_merge function. Only comment: c has to be defined before used.