# Merge time to time period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with measurements, containing the values of the measurement and the times.

```
time = [datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, np.random.randint(0,23), np.random.randint(1, 59)) for _ in xrange(10)]
df_meas = pandas.DataFrame({'time': time, 'value': np.random.random(10)})
```

for example:

```
                 time     value
0 2011-01-01 21:56:00  0.115025
1 2011-01-01 04:40:00  0.678882
2 2011-01-01 02:18:00  0.507168
3 2011-01-01 22:40:00  0.938408
4 2011-01-01 12:53:00  0.193573
5 2011-01-01 19:37:00  0.464744
6 2011-01-01 16:06:00  0.794495
7 2011-01-01 18:32:00  0.482684
8 2011-01-01 13:26:00  0.381747
9 2011-01-01 01:50:00  0.035798
```

the data-taking is organized in periods and I have another `DataFrame` for it:

```
start = pandas.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H')
stop = start + np.timedelta64(50, 'm')
df_runs = pandas.DataFrame({'start': start, 'stop': stop}, index=np.random.randint(0, 1000000, 5))
df_runs.index.name = 'run'
```

for example:

```
                     start                stop
run                                           
721158 2011-01-01 00:00:00 2011-01-01 00:50:00
340902 2011-01-01 01:00:00 2011-01-01 01:50:00
211578 2011-01-01 02:00:00 2011-01-01 02:50:00
120232 2011-01-01 03:00:00 2011-01-01 03:50:00
122199 2011-01-01 04:00:00 2011-01-01 04:50:00
```

Now I want to merge the two tables, obtaining:

```
                 time     value   run
0 2011-01-01 21:56:00  0.115025   NaN
1 2011-01-01 04:40:00  0.678882   122199  
2 2011-01-01 02:18:00  0.507168   211578 
3 2011-01-01 22:40:00  0.938408   NaN
...
```

time periods (`run`s) have a `start` and a `stop` and `stop >= start`. Different runs never overlap. (Even if in my example it is not true) you can assume that runs are ordered (by `run`) and if `run1 < run2` then `start1 < start2` (or you can simply sort the table by `start`). You can also assume that `df_meas` is sorted by `time`.

How to do that? Is there something build in? What is the most efficient way?

Comment: Did one of the answers work?

Comment: @IanS: it seems to me that none take advantage of the fact that the tables are sorted. I would expect to see some search_sorted method or similar.

Comment: Actually I believe that, behind the scenes, `asof` takes advantage of the fact that the times are sorted.

Comment: There you go! [`loc = self.index.searchsorted(where, side='right')`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L2636)

Comment: Are you still not convinced?

Answer (score 2):

You can first reshape `df_runs` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - `start` and `stop` are in one column `time`. Then `groupby` by `run`, [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) by `minutes` and [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) for filling `NaN` values. Last [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) to `df_meas`:

Notice - this code works in last `pandas` version `0.18.1` [see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as datetime

#for testing
np.random.seed(1)
time = [datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, np.random.randint(0,23), np.random.randint(1, 59)) for _ in range(10)]
df_meas = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'value': np.random.random(10)})

start = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H')
stop = start + np.timedelta64(50, 'm')
df_runs = pd.DataFrame({'start': start, 'stop': stop}, index=np.random.randint(0, 1000000, 5))
df_runs.index.name = 'run'
```

```
df = (df_runs.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='time'))
print (df)
      run                time
0   99335 2011-01-01 00:00:00
1   99335 2011-01-01 00:50:00
2  823615 2011-01-01 01:00:00
3  823615 2011-01-01 01:50:00
4  117565 2011-01-01 02:00:00
5  117565 2011-01-01 02:50:00
6  790038 2011-01-01 03:00:00
7  790038 2011-01-01 03:50:00
8  369977 2011-01-01 04:00:00
9  369977 2011-01-01 04:50:00

df1 = (df.set_index('time')
         .groupby('run')
         .resample('Min')
         .ffill()
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
                   time     run
0   2011-01-01 00:00:00   99335
1   2011-01-01 00:01:00   99335
2   2011-01-01 00:02:00   99335
3   2011-01-01 00:03:00   99335
4   2011-01-01 00:04:00   99335
5   2011-01-01 00:05:00   99335
6   2011-01-01 00:06:00   99335
7   2011-01-01 00:07:00   99335
8   2011-01-01 00:08:00   99335
9   2011-01-01 00:09:00   99335
...
...
```

```
print (pd.merge(df_meas, df1, on='time', how='left'))
                 time     value       run
0 2011-01-01 05:44:00  0.524548       NaN
1 2011-01-01 12:09:00  0.443453       NaN
2 2011-01-01 09:12:00  0.229577       NaN
3 2011-01-01 05:16:00  0.534414       NaN
4 2011-01-01 00:17:00  0.913962   99335.0
5 2011-01-01 01:13:00  0.457205  823615.0
6 2011-01-01 07:46:00  0.430699       NaN
7 2011-01-01 06:26:00  0.939128       NaN
8 2011-01-01 18:21:00  0.778389       NaN
9 2011-01-01 05:19:00  0.715971       NaN
```

Solution of [`IanS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386827/2901002) is very nice, and I try improve it with `pd.lreshape`:

```
df_runs['run1'] = -1 
df_runs = df_runs.reset_index()

run_times = (pd.lreshape(df_runs, {'Run':['run', 'run1'], 
                                   'Time':['start', 'stop']})
               .sort_values('Time')
               .set_index('Time'))

print (run_times['Run'].asof(df_meas['time']))

time
2011-01-01 05:44:00        -1
2011-01-01 12:09:00        -1
2011-01-01 09:12:00        -1
2011-01-01 05:16:00        -1
2011-01-01 00:17:00     99335
2011-01-01 01:13:00    823615
2011-01-01 07:46:00        -1
2011-01-01 06:26:00        -1
2011-01-01 18:21:00        -1
2011-01-01 05:19:00        -1
Name: Run, dtype: int64
```

Comment: are you taking advantage by the sorting of the inputs?

Comment: No, this is general solution. But I have idea, give me a time and add other solution too.

Comment: I add new solution, but unfortunately `sort_values('Time')` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I had never heard of `lreshape`.

Comment: It is no widely used, but you can check it in `spyder` - `help(pd.lreshape)`. I never heard about `asof`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As suggested in a comment, there is no need to sort the times. Rather, use `stack` instead of `unstack`.

**First step**: transform the times dataframe

Since the start and end times are nicely ordered, I set them as index. I also add a column with the run id for starts, and `NaN` for stops. I do this in many lines (hopefully each one self-explanatory), but you could certainly condense the code:

```
run_times = df_runs.stack().to_frame(name='times')
run_times.reset_index(inplace=True)
run_times['actual_run'] = np.where(run_times['level_1'] == 'start', run_times['run'], np.nan)
run_times.drop(['level_1', 'run'], axis=1, inplace=True)
run_times.set_index('times', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
In[101] : run_times
Out[101]: 
                     actual_run
times                          
2011-01-01 00:00:00      110343
2011-01-01 00:50:00         NaN
2011-01-01 01:00:00      839451
2011-01-01 01:50:00         NaN
2011-01-01 02:00:00      742879
2011-01-01 02:50:00         NaN
2011-01-01 03:00:00      275509
2011-01-01 03:50:00         NaN
2011-01-01 04:00:00      788777
2011-01-01 04:50:00         NaN
```

**Second step**: lookup the values

You can now look this up in the original dataframe with the `asof` method:

```
In[131] : run_times['actual_run'].fillna(-1).asof(df_meas['time'])
Out[131]: 
2011-01-01 21:56:00        -1
2011-01-01 04:40:00    122199
2011-01-01 02:18:00    211578
2011-01-01 22:40:00        -1
2011-01-01 12:53:00        -1
```

Note that I had to use `-1` instead of `NaN` because `asof` returns the last valid value.

Comment: are you taking advantage by the sorting of the inputs?

Comment: I sort them in order to alternate a start and stop times. But now that I think of it there should be a better way. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

If you want to benefit from tables being sorted, sometimes (or usually) it's better to leave it to pandas (or numpy). For example with merging two sorted arrays, there is not much you can do by hand, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27918384/5717589) suggests. And pandas uses low level functions to do it automatically.

I measured time used by `asof` (as in `A.asof(I)`) and it looked as if it didn't benefit from `I` being sorted. But I don't see an easy way to beat it, if at all it's possible.

In my tests, `asof` was even faster than `.loc` when the index (`A.index`) already contained `I`. The only object I know of that could take advantage of the indices being sorted is `pd.Index`. And indeed, `A.reindex(idx)` for `idx = pd.Index(I)` was much faster (to use it, `A.index` has to be unique). Unfortunately, the time needed to build the right data frame or series outweighed the benefits.

---

The answer by @IanS and @jezrael are very fast. In fact, most of the time (almost 40%) in jezrael's second function is spent in `lreshape`. `sort_values` and `asof` take up to 15%.

Certainly, it's possible to optimize it further. The results are quite good, so I put it here.

I use the following setup to generate sorted data frames for testing:

```
def setup(intervals, periods):
    time = [datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, np.random.randint(0,23), np.random.randint(1, 59)) for _ in range(intervals)]
    df_meas = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'value': np.random.random(intervals)})
    df_meas = df_meas.sort_values(by='time')
    df_meas.index = range(df_meas.shape[0])

    start = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=periods, freq='H')
    stop = start + np.timedelta64(50, 'm')
    df_runs = pd.DataFrame({'start': start, 'stop': stop}, index=np.unique(np.random.randint(0, 1000000, periods)))
    df_runs.index.name = 'run'

    return df_meas, df_runs
```

The function benefits from the use of `asof` and some tricks to cut down unnecessary formatting.

```
def run(df_meas, df_runs):
    run_times = pd.Series(np.concatenate([df_runs.index, [-1] * df_runs.shape[0]]),
                      index=df_runs.values.flatten(order='F'))
    run_times.sort_index(inplace=True)
    return run_times.asof(df_meas['time'])
```

I tested it with `intervals=100` and `periods=20`. The results measured with timeit:

```
# @jezrael's second function: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.43 ms per loop
# @IanS's function:
100 loops, best of 3: 3.92 ms per loop
# my function:
1000 loops, best of 3: 752 µs per loop
```

Answer (score -1):

The `merge()` function could be used to merge 2 dataframes horizontally:

```
merge(x, y, by ="name")  # merge df x and y using the "name" column
```

So you may have to rename the "start" col of the first dataframe in "time" and have a try...

Comment: definitively not so easy, I am talking of time intervals