# Merging arrays and plots

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have 2 arrays like these:

```
x1 = [ 1.2,  1.8,  2.3,  4.5, 20.0]
y1 = [10.3, 11.8, 12.3, 11.5, 11.5]
```

and other two that represent the same function but sampled in different values

```
x2 = [ 0.2,  1,8,  5.3, 15.5, 17.2, 18.3, 20.0]
y2 = [10.3, 11.8, 12.3, 12.5, 15.2, 10.3, 10.0]
```

is there a way with numpy to merge x1 and x2 and according to the result merging also the related values of y without explicitly looping all over the arrays? (like doing an average of y or taking the max for that interval)

Comment: Do you have an expected output? `x = x1 + x2; y = y1 + y2`??

Comment: What about interpolation / extrapolation? I mean if you have two sets of measurements... most likely they will be slightly different. Going that direction - is it ok to check only x-es, or maybe you wish to validate point? Other question is how big difference should be to say that two things are different?

Comment: ... and points that are interpolated / extrapolated with linear function are different then extrapolating with other functions ...

Comment: Since your two examples both have `20.0` as x-values but have different y-values for `20.0`, how can the two arrays represent the same function? This is just one way your question is not clear. Please add more explanation and handle the `20.0` issue.

Comment: yeah sorry for not remarking that y should be interpolated in some way. So concatenation and merge are good for x, but y should change according to a rule (like average, or max or some custom thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can find something in numpy, but here is a solution using pandas instead. (Pandas is using numpy behind the scenes, so there isn't so much data conversion.)

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
x1 = np.asarray([ 1.2,  1.8,  2.3,  4.5, 20.0])
y1 = np.asarray([10.3, 11.8, 12.3, 11.5, 11.5])
x2 = np.asarray([ 0.2,  1.8,  5.3, 15.5, 17.2, 18.3, 20.0])
y2 = np.asarray([10.3, 11.8, 12.3, 12.5, 15.2, 10.3, 10.0])
c1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x1, 'y': y1})
c2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x2, 'y': y2})
c = pd.concat([c1, c2]).groupby('x').mean().reset_index()
x = c['x'].values
y = c['y'].values

# Result:
x = array([ 0.2,  1.2,  1.8,  2.3,  4.5,  5.3,  15.5, 17.2, 18.3, 20. ])
y = array([10.3 , 10.3, 11.8, 12.3, 11.5, 12.3, 12.5, 15.2, 10.3, 10.75])
```

Here I concatenate the two vectors and do a groupby operation to get the equal values for 'x'. For these "groups" I than take the mean(). reset_index() will than move the index 'x' back to a column. To get the result back as a numpy array I use .values. (Use to_numpy() for pandas version 24.0 and higher.)

Answer (score 0):

How about using [**`numpy.hstack`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) followed by sorting using [**`numpy.sort`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) ?

```
In [101]: x1_arr = np.array(x1)
In [102]: x2_arr = np.array(x2)

In [103]: y1_arr = np.array(y1)
In [104]: y2_arr = np.array(y2)


In [111]: np.sort(np.hstack((x1_arr, x2_arr)))
Out[111]: 
array([ 0.2,  1.2,  1.8,  1.8,  2.3,  4.5,  5.3, 15.5, 17.2, 18.3, 20. ,
       20. ])

In [112]: np.sort(np.hstack((y1_arr, y2_arr)))
Out[112]: 
array([10. , 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 11.5, 11.5, 11.8, 11.8, 12.3, 12.3, 12.5,
       15.2])
```

---

If you want to get rid of the duplicates, you can apply [**`numpy.unique`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on top of the above results.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose a solution based on the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427146/combine-two-arrays-and-sort):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

x1 = [1.2, 1.8, 2.3, 4.5, 20.0]
y1 = [10.3, 11.8, 12.3, 11.5, 11.5]

x2 = [0.2, 1.8, 5.3, 15.5, 17.2, 18.3, 20.0]
y2 = [10.3, 11.8, 12.3, 12.5, 15.2, 10.3, 10.0]

# create a merged and sorted x array
x = np.concatenate((x1, x2))
ids = x.argsort(kind='mergesort')
x = x[ids]

# find unique values
flag = np.ones_like(x, dtype=bool)
np.not_equal(x[1:], x[:-1], out=flag[1:])

# discard duplicated values
x = x[flag]

# merge, sort and select values for y
y = np.concatenate((y1, y2))[ids][flag]

plt.plot(x, y, marker='s', color='b', ls='-.')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[image]

```
x = [ 0.2  1.2  1.8  2.3  4.5  5.3 15.5 17.2 18.3 20. ] 
y = [10.3 10.3 11.8 12.3 11.5 12.3 12.5 15.2 10.3 11.5]
```

As you notice, this code keeps only one value for `y` if several ones are available for the same `x`: in this way, the code is faster.

***Bonus solution***: the following solution is based on a loop and mainly standard Python functions and objects (not numpy), so I known that it is not acceptable; by the way, it is very coincise and elegant and it handles multiple values for `y`, so I decied to include it here as a plus:

```
x = sorted(set(x1 + x2))
y = np.nanmean([[d.get(i, np.nan) for i in x] 
                for d in map(lambda a: dict(zip(*a)), ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)))], axis=0)
```

In this case, you get the following results:

```
x = [0.2, 1.2, 1.8, 2.3, 4.5, 5.3, 15.5, 17.2, 18.3, 20.0] 
y = [10.3  10.3  11.8  12.3  11.5  12.3  12.5  15.2  10.3  10.75]
```