# numpy: How to merge two sorted arrays into a larger sorted array?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have two sorted np.arrays, say

```
1, 2, 3, 5
```

and

```
2, 4, 6, 7
```

I want

```
1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Don't want python for loops.

Is there some numpy function for this?

---

Bonus: do this for matrices by some axis (other axes have the same shape)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916710/numpy-merge-sorted-array-to-an-new-array

Comment: This seems to be agreed upon as the fastest solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427146/combine-two-arrays-and-sort/12427633#12427633

Comment: Are those unique numbers in the input arrays?

Comment: @Divakar No, but I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abusing the sorted nature of the input arrays, we can use `np.searchsorted`, like so -

```
def merge_sorted_arrays(a, b):
    m,n = len(a), len(b)
    # Get searchsorted indices
    idx = np.searchsorted(a,b)

    # Offset each searchsorted indices with ranged array to get new positions
    # of b in output array
    b_pos = np.arange(n) + idx

    l = m+n
    mask = np.ones(l,dtype=bool)
    out = np.empty(l,dtype=np.result_type(a,b))
    mask[b_pos] = False
    out[b_pos] = b
    out[mask] = a
    return out
```

Sample run (using a generic case of duplicates) -

```
In [52]: a
Out[52]: array([1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 9])

In [53]: b
Out[53]: array([ 2,  4,  6,  6,  6,  7, 10])

In [54]: merge_sorted_arrays(a, b)
Out[54]: array([ 1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  9,  9,  9, 10])
```

Timimgs on random-sorted `1000000` sized arrays -

Benchmarking against the popular concatenate+sort method.

```
# Setup
In [141]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,1000000,(1000000)))
     ...: b = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,1000000,(1000000)))

# @chmod777's soln
In [142]: %%timeit
     ...: c = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)
     ...: c.sort()
141 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [143]: %timeit merge_sorted_arrays(a, b)
55.1 ms ± 5.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: could you please explain the `((a[idx]==b) | v)
` part? I'm guessing it has to do with duplicates, but can't figure out the logic exactly

Comment: @Gulzar Simplified that part and added comments and some timings.

Comment: Looks like you deleted that part... Am i missing something?

Comment: @Gulzar That part wasn't needed, hence deleted.

Comment: Explicitely using mergesort as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427633/7951589) largely increases performance of concatenate-sort method. My benchmark numbers: concatenate-sort, default kind: 137ms; concatenate-sort, mergesort kind: 14.8ms; This answer: 57.6ms; [sortednp merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59263257/7951589): 9.65ms.

Comment: @KoenG Worth noting that this speedup requires a recent version of numpy and depends a bit on the data type as kind="mergesort" despite its name doesn't actually use mergesort but maps to `radix sort` or `tim sort`.

Answer (score 5):

Import sortednp and you're good to go:

```
import numpy as np
import sortednp as s

a = np.array([1,2,3,5])
b = np.array([2,4,6,7])

m = s.merge(a, b)
print(m)
```

Comment: Would accept, but i preferred a native numpy solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The numpy devs recently implemented tim sort. As tim sort checks for presorted sub-sequences it will sort the concatenation of two sorted arrays in O(n).

For some reason it is currently not possible to directly select tim sort, but at least in some cases `kind="stable"` results in tim sort being used. Integer types use radix sort which is also O(n). 
See official docs for more detail https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

At size 10^6 this results  in a 10-fold speedup compared to the default sorting method (qsort, I believe).

tim sort/radix sort is also only a tiny bit slower than `sortednp.merge`.

```
# default sort
def so():
    c = np.concatenate((a,b))
    c.sort()
    return c

# tim sort / radix sort
def ts():
    c = np.concatenate((a,b))
    c.sort(kind="stable")
    return c

from sortednp import merge

# extra library
def mg():
    return merge(a,b)

# @Divakar's example (range enlarged)
a = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,100000000,(1000000)))
b = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,100000000,(1000000)))

timeit(so,number=10)
# 1.5669178580283187
timeit(ts,number=10)
# 0.12706473504658788
timeit(mg,number=10)
# 0.12382328097010031

# for comparison @Divakar's solution
timeit(lambda:merge_sorted_arrays(a,b),number=10)
# 0.5367169310338795

# non integer example
a = np.sort(np.random.random(1000000))
b = np.sort(np.random.random(1000000))

timeit(so,number=10)
# 1.7868053679703735
timeit(ts,number=10)
# 0.17676723399199545
timeit(mg,number=10)
# 0.1376464170170948

# and @Divakar
timeit(lambda:merge_sorted_arrays(a,b),number=10)
# 0.5656043770140968
```